# .rviz/config and display_config do not exist

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running ubuntu 10.4, electric.  I'm trying to start rviz (which used to work).  Apart from segmentation fault that seems to be common, I notice that I do not have a config or display_config file in my .rviz directory.  When and how are these generated?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11390/.rviz/config-and-display_config-do-not-exist/) by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 271 on 2011-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My config files are modified every time that I close Rviz so that it can preserve the settings that I used last. This is the default behavior on my machine. Rviz also has a "save configuration" option in the menu.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1